# Getting unexpected EOF with HTTP2 Transport

Tags: go, eof, http2

Was trying out the http2 package in go, and while creating an HTTP2 connection I am getting an unexpected EOF error. Not able to figure out the exact issue.

```
    tcpConn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "clients1.google.com:443")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer tcpConn.Close()

    t := http2.Transport{}
    http2ClientConn, err := t.NewClientConn(tcpConn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://clients1.google.com/generate_204", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    resp, err := http2ClientConn.RoundTrip(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // getting unexpected EOF
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)
```

**Output**

```
panic: unexpected EOF

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /Users/rishabharya/Desktop/Projects/src/github.com/rishabh-arya95/raw_http/main.go:31 +0x217
exit status 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [TLS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446) encryption with [Application-Layer Protocol Negotiation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7301) (ALPN).

### What happens?

1. Client [establish](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Dial) network connection to server.
2. Client [sends](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/http2#ClientConn.RoundTrip) a request using [HTTP/2 protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540).
3. Server receives the data and expects it to be part of [TLS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446) [Handshake](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-4) protocol.
4. Server has to close the connection because the data does not satisfy [TLS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446) protocol.
5. An [io.ErrUnexpectedEOF](https://pkg.go.dev/io#pkg-variables) error is returned because the connection was closed before the response was read.

### What needs to be change

The client establishes a connection to the [standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2818#section-2.3) HTTPS port (port number is [443](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=https)), but use [net.Dial()](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Dial) function. [HTTPS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2818) protocol [use](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2818#section-2) [TLS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446) to secure HTTP connection over the Internet. Therefore, the client have to use [tls.Dial()](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Dial) function to establish a connection:

```
tcpConn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "clients1.google.com:443", new(tls.Config))
```

However, the client cannot use an empty [TLS configuration](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Config). In this particular case, the server supports both protocols: [HTTP/1.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230) and [HTTP/2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2818). By default, the server uses HTTP/1.1 protocol. There are two ways to request the use of HTTP/2 protocol:

- Use [Application-Layer Protocol Negotiation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7301) (ALPN) [extension](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-4.2) of TLS protocol.
- Use the [HTTP Upgrade](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-6.7) mechanism.

The second method is not suitable. The first reason is that [http2](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/http2) package is not intended for this. The second reason is that the server ignores HTTP Upgrade mechanism for the given request.

In order to use the first methods, we need to add "h2" [identifier](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-3.1) to a list of supported application level protocols (a list of [all registered identifiers](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-extensiontype-values/tls-extensiontype-values.xhtml#alpn-protocol-ids) can be found on [IANA](https://www.iana.org/about) website).

```
conf := & tls.Config {
    NextProtos: []string{"h2"},
}

tcpConn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "clients1.google.com:443", conf)
```

### Working Code

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "golang.org/x/net/http2"
)

func main() {
    conf := & tls.Config {
        NextProtos: []string{"h2"},
    }
    tcpConn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "clients1.google.com:443", conf)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer tcpConn.Close()

    t := http2.Transport{}
    http2ClientConn, err := t.NewClientConn(tcpConn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://clients1.google.com/generate_204", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    resp, err := http2ClientConn.RoundTrip(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)

}
```

And a slightly [modified version](https://go.dev/play/p/N8ufzJLow6s).

---

[cURL](https://curl.se) is a handy tool for checking.

Make an HTTP/2 request:

```
 $ curl -i --http2 https://clients1.google.com/generate_204
-| HTTP/2 204
```

Disable Application-Layer Protocol Negotiation (ALPN):

```
 $ curl -i --http2 --no-alpn https://clients1.google.com/generate_204
-| HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
```

Send an HTTP/2 request without Application-Layer Protocol Negotiation (ALPN):

```
 $ curl -i --http2-prior-knowledge --no-alpn https://clients1.google.com/generate_204
-| curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Error [52](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#52): The server did not reply anything, which here is considered an error.

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| [-i](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-i) | Include the HTTP response headers in the output. |
| [-v](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-v) | Makes curl verbose during the operation. |
|  |  |
| [--no-alpn](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-no-alpn) | Disable the ALPN TLS extension. |
|  |  |
| [--http2](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--http2) | Tells curl to use HTTP version 2. |
| [--http2-prior-knowledge](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--http2-prior-knowledge) | Tells curl to use HTTP version 2. |

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was really helpful. One thing I am not sure about is the  http2.Transport https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/http2#Transport also creates the TLS connection but even if I specify the same TLS config as above it still throws EOF, but if we create TLS connection separately it works fine.

Comment: Please provide the source code and I will check it out. [Here](https://go.dev/play/p/7ajovvt0a7w) is an example using [http2.Transport](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/http2#Transport) without creating a connection.

Comment: Here you go https://go.dev/play/p/wICILh4dasa, It is almost the same as my sample code just specified the tls config specifically this time.

Comment: [This](https://go.dev/play/p/wICILh4dasa) code contains [the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72343680/14921878). You should use [tls.Dial()](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Dial), not [net.Dial()](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Dial).

Comment: You can use [Transport.RoundTrip()](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/http2#Transport.RoundTrip) and then you don't need to create a connection. Example: new(http2.Transport).RoundTrip(req)